# MySQL SELECT all with expected datetime older than 24 hours

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli, date-arithmetic

Database structure contains a datetime column in "2014-09-22 21:16:00" format.

I want to SELECT everything where the datetime is older than 24 hours.

Example data:

```
    datetime
    2014-10-15 21:00:00
    2014-10-15 22:10:00
```

SELECT * FROM table WHERE $datetime is older than 24 hours.

Current Datetime is for example 2014-10-16 21:01:00 yet.

Result should be:

```
    2014-10-15 21:00:00
```

I want to SELECT with the current datetime.

I've tried following, but it does not work:

```
    SELECT id, datetime FROM table WHERE customerNumber="1" AND datetime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Hope, somebody can help me. :/

Comment: Please show `CustomerNumber` in your sample data. Is it `'1'`? Also, I know SQL Server, not MySQL. Is the `"1"` supposed to be `'1'` in single-quotes in your `SELECT` statement?

Comment: *"I've tried following, but it does not work:"* - Define `doesn't work`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may try :

```
SELECT id, datetime FROM TABLE WHERE customerNumber="1" AND HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), datetime))>24;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, datetime FROM table WHERE customerNumber="1" AND datetime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Comment: What's this apart from you repeating the `SELECT` statement from your question?